# Android - Using Thread on my method is force closing my app

Tags: android, multithreading, sleep

I am creating a thread and starting it, inside one of my methods, and after the sleep, the app just closes :s
Cant understand why.. Any clues??
Here is my code:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    if(!toggleRemove){
                        grupo.increment();
                        vibrate();

                    }else
                        grupo.decrement();
                    showToPanel(grupo);
                    new Thread(){
                        public void run(){
                            try {
                                sleep(3000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            showToPanel(null);
                        }
                    }.start();

                }

            });
```

Thanks alot in advance!!

Got it fixed using this instead:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    if(!toggleRemove){
                        grupo.increment();
                        vibrate();

                    }else
                        grupo.decrement();
                    showToPanel(grupo);



                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                        @Override
                        public void run(){
                           showToPanel(null);
                        }
                    }, 3000); 

                }

            });
```

Comment: What does showToPanel do? Does it update the UI?

Comment: Yes mate, it does. But I got it already fixed it, didnt know that I couldnt use normal threads here at android development.. Used the handler thing and it worked . thanks alot anyway dude! really appreciated ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please post full stack traces when posting crashing bugs.  But my guess is that showToPanel makes changes to the UI?  If so, you can't do that on another thread, you must do it on the main thread.  The best way to do this is to post a delayed message to a handler and change the UI in there, since there is no real work other than a sleep to be done on the other thread.

Comment: Yes mate, it does. But I got it already fixed it, didnt know that I couldnt use normal threads here at android development.. Used the handler thing and it worked . thanks alot anyway dude! really appreciated ;)

Comment: You can use (normal) Threads to your heart's content (although AsyncTasks are preferred). You just can't use a non-UI thread (i.e. background thread) to make changes to the UI.

Comment: AsyncTasks are preferred if it's a task to do something right now one time.  Normal threads are still preferred if you're going to be doing something constantly in the background, especially if you want to ensure only 1 instance of the worker exists.